# Manullay run any service on reboot

Tags: files, systemd, filesystems, services, reboot

I want to run a service on linux on reboot. I know i can do

sudo systemctl enable service_name.service

To run this service on reboot. But I can't use terminal. So, Is there any way that i could run this service on reboot without the help of terminal.

I mean that command would also did some changes to any files or location. So, i will make changes to those locations. If still you have any doubt you may ask me , but please tell.

Comment: You may give me any command which don't need sudo priviledge to run

Answer (score 0):

Running `sudo systemctl enable service_name.service` would create a symbolic link in the directory of the target specified in the `[Install]` section of the service file. Most commonly the directory will be `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/`. The link will be named `service_name.service` and pointing to the actual location of the file `service_name.service`.

In other words, if `service_name.service` is located at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/service_name.service` and its `[Install]` section says `WantedBy=multi-user.target`, the equivalent basic command would be:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/system/service_name.service /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/service_name.service
```

If you can perform the equivalent of that action as root, with whatever unspecified tools you have available, it will be effectively the same as running `systemctl enable service_name.service`.